# Use JOSE JWE for encryption of big files

Tags: encryption, jwt, encryption-symmetric, jwe, jose

I need to encrypt some bigger files < 1GB in a secure and efficient way.
Is it a good idea to use JOSE JWE libraries for that purpose?
Is there any other option you can recommend?

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea.
JWE stands for Encrypted JSON Web tokens and is meant to be used in a web context (i.e. HTTP/HTTPS protocols).
The payload is encrypted but also encoded in base64 url safe and thus the size of the encrypted payload will be larger than the original file (approx. +30% overhead) plus the header, encrypted CEK and IV.

A 1GB file will be encrypted into a 1.3GB token…

**You should definitively choose a dedicated and secured file transfert protocol e.g. SCP or SFTP**